# PHP function can match HTML comment pattern and remove HTML code

Tags: php, html, regex

I have few files on my server, I just need help, whenever following HTML code identifies in my HTML, PHP function match and remove following block of code.

```
<!---- 728x90 Ad START ---->
    <iframe marginheight="" marginwidth="" src="728.html" height="728" width="90" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
<!---- END 728x90 Ad ---->

<!---- 160x600 Ad START ---->
    <iframe marginheight="" marginwidth="" src="160.html" height="160" width="600" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
<!---- END 160x600  Ad ---->


<!---- 300x250 Ad START ---->
    <iframe marginheight="" marginwidth="" src="300.html" height="300" width="150" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
<!---- END 300x250 Ad ---->
```

Comment: i didn't get what exactly are you asking ?

Comment: Can you show us your PHP code? That makes it easier for us to give you feedback.

Comment: Do you need to remove the comments with word "Ad START" and "END  Ad" and the HTML between them?

Comment: i am using iframe code in my static html file, now i need one php function, when my ads iframe code appear , first php function match following comment star and end block, then all code between comment, removed.

Answer (score 2):

Usually it's a bad practice to use regular expressions for HTML parsing. But as your ads comments have similar pattern, we can remove them, using a regexp.

```
<?php
$text = '
<!---- 728x90 Ad START ---->
    <iframe marginheight="" marginwidth="" src="728.html" height="728" width="90" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
<!---- END 728x90 Ad ---->

HTML code here

<!---- 160x600 Ad START ---->
    <iframe marginheight="" marginwidth="" src="160.html" height="160" width="600" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
<!---- END 160x600  Ad ---->

HTML code 2 here

<!---- 300x250 Ad START ---->
    <iframe marginheight="" marginwidth="" src="300.html" height="300" width="150" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
<!---- END 300x250 Ad ---->
';

//s modifier ignores newlines
$text = preg_replace('/<!-.*?Ad START.*?Ad.*?->/s', '', $text);
print $text;
```

Output:

```
HTML code here

HTML code 2 here
```

**Regular expression comments**

```
<!-      | starts with "<!-"
.*?      | something
Ad START | text "Ad START"
.*?      | something
Ad       | text "Ad"
.*?      | something
->       | ends with "->"
```

Comment: Please explain following code: $text = preg_replace('/<!-.*?Ad START.*?Ad.*?->/s', '', $text);

Comment: @Ahmediqbal I commented the regexp for you

Comment: wow! preg_replace is a very powerful function, i think i need some type of loop to test whole html code, very helpful and elegant solution for me, thanks very much :)